# How to change the resolution of a video (React-Native)

Tags: react-native, video, video-streaming

Basically title, i'm trying to change the resolution of the videos because they are too heavy, i'm using react-native-video to display the videos and i saw that it has a selectedVideoTrack which can be used to change it but it is not working for me. could i be using it wrong?

```
<Video
selectedVideoTrack={{
  type: "resolution",
  value: 240
}}
resizeMode = "stretch"
source={{ uri: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4' }}
style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}
controls={true}
ref={(ref) => {
this.player = ref
}} />
```